# Script/Program to connect iTunes and Spotify

Tags: vbscript, itunes, spotify

So I am trying to either play a song in spotify and have it update the playcount of the song in iTunes. Or when I play a song in iTunes to have it play in Spotify. either is fine.

I have a vbs script that can increment the playcount of a song if it matches a folder path on iTunes. However I don't know how to get that path of Spotify. As far as the second option I have no clue how to do it.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Spotify doesn't really provide access to the currently playing song, so what you're attempting to do is probably not really feasible. I would suggest maybe using something like Last.FM to save overall playcounts.

I wrote a script in Python which can update iTunes with playcounts from Last.FM http://deceptacle.com/2010/10/21/itunes-playcount-updater-using-last-fm/ which may be of some use